# Are there any other way to do this?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have this form where employees can send feedbacks.

[image]

I have two tables, employee and tbl_feedback.

The `employee_id` in my tbl_feedback references `id` in my employee table.

Now my question is, are there any other way to make it work **without putting Employee ID** on my form?

Comment: unclear as to the issue

Comment: You mean use a hidden field?

Comment: Just hide your input of employee id. `<input type='hidden' value='your employee id'>`

Comment: @MinhDuc That's what I wanted to know, dunno why it's unclear for some people :/ Post it as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: It's ok. Glad I can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make the form field hidden.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{employee id here}}" />
```